# How to remove nbsp characters from metabox?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WPAlchemy for some custom media upload metaboxes. Everything going well, it's a wonderful framework for WP. One minor annoyance that I'm hoping someone can find a solution to. The outputted html within my metabox, specifically around divs, renders a bunch of nbsp characters. These are annoying to style against. At first I thought this was just how things were done, but after viewing some screencasts of other custom metabox examples, I'd notice these weren't there. Anyone have ideas on how these can be removed? I'm running WP 3.6.1 and WPAlchemy 1.5.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use one of these php methods:
1) `trim(html_entity_decode($html));` or
2) `str_replace("&nbsp;","",$html);` or
3) `preg_replace("/&nbsp;/",'',$html);`

I assume the content here is generated by php so it should accessible from a variable just feed it to one of those methods and it should clean it up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so big WP newbie here, what filter/callback would be most appropriate to place this cleanup code in?